# Resources.Load или Instantiate

Tags: unity3d, производительность

Нужно реализовать инвентарь. Во многих "уроках" на YouTube в каждом предмете, который нужно помещать в инвентарь, хранят путь к префабу предмета и иконке для ячейки инвентаря. Почему именно так? Есть ли смысл хранить сразу ссылку на префаб?

Таким образом есть два варианта:

1. Хранить путь к префабу как строку и, когда нужно, вызывать Recources.Load
2. Хранить ссылку на префаб и, когда нужно, вызывать сразу Instantiate

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше поступить, сточки зрения производительности и затрат ресурсов памяти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй лучше, но дороже по используемой памяти. Сделай адаптируемый вариант, пометь объекты, которые часто используются и много не весят, храни ссылку на префаб. Другие объекты можно подгружать и хранить ссылку, но если в течении n-го времени не используются, то удалять ссылку  и  выгружать через Resources.UnloadAsset